Compositing - Using ambient occlusion as alpha
I'm trying to composite the ambient occlusion pass and use it as a "fake" shadow in my render.
In my scene I have

a sphere with a simple material
a plane with a principled material

I cannot manage to export a good shadow with a shadow catcher, I just want to fake it using the ambient occlusion pass.

This is the output of the Ambient Occlusion pass.
Now, I have two problems:

Why is the Ambient Occlusion on a gray base instead of pure white with black occlusions?
How can I use this pass to say to the compositor: "ok, create a black layer which is black where the AO is black, and transparent where the AO is white"?

Thank you very much
